# Handling remainders within an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a query where I want to allocate the tax amount over the lines in A10501.  This works, except that I would want to have any remainder amount added to the last line of the update.

Consider A20601 has an amount of $14.14 in total that needs to be allocated over four lines in A10501.  Each line would get 3.535 if spread across evenly, but I would like the update to be:

```
Line 1: 3.53
Line 2: 3.53
Line 3: 3.53
Line 4: 3.55 = total of 14.14
```

Here is the query I came up with:

```
-- Replace 'your_invcnmbr_value' with the specific INVCNMBR you want to allocate
DECLARE @target_invcnmbr NVARCHAR(50) = 'INV001';

-- Create a local temporary table to store the total amount and row count from A20601
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (
    RowNum INT,
    INVCNMBR NVARCHAR(50),
    SumTXDTLAMT DECIMAL(18, 2),
    rowz INT
);

INSERT INTO #temp_table (RowNum, INVCNMBR, SumTXDTLAMT, rowz)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum,
    INVCNMBR,
    ROUND(SUM(TXDTLAMT), 2) AS SumTXDTLAMT,
    COUNT(*) AS rowz
FROM
    A20601
WHERE
    INVCNMBR = @target_invcnmbr
GROUP BY
    INVCNMBR;

-- Update A10501 table
UPDATE A10501
SET
FEETXAMT = ROUND(FEETXAMT + (t.SumTXDTLAMT / t.rowz) + 
             CASE WHEN t.RowNum = t.rowz THEN t.SumTXDTLAMT % t.rowz ELSE 0 END, 2),
OTFTXAMT = ROUND(OTFTXAMT + (t.SumTXDTLAMT / t.rowz) +
             CASE WHEN t.RowNum = t.rowz THEN t.SumTXDTLAMT % t.rowz ELSE 0 END, 2)
FROM
P10501 p
JOIN #temp_table t ON p.INVCNMBR = t.INVCNMBR
WHERE
p.INVCNMBR = @target_invcnmbr;

-- Drop the temporary table when done
DROP TABLE #temp_table;
```

I want two decimals to update the table, with the remainder being added to the last line of the update.  Right now it will create three decimals, which we do not want

Comment: Please also show sample data from `A20601` and `P10501` and the expected result

Comment: One way to allocated amounts is to calculate `ROUND(Amount * i / N, precision)` for each `i in 0..N` and then calculate each allocated portion as the difference between successive values. Since the i=0 value is always 0, and the i = N value always equals Amount, the sum of the intervals will exactly total Amount. An alternate way or representing the calculation is `Allocated(i)` **=** `ROUND(Amount * i / N, precision) - ROUND(Amount * (i-1) / N, precision)`. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FypOezLJ).

Comment: To allocate all residuals to the last portion, you need to use `FLOOR()` instead of ROUND() to calculate the base allocated amount. Since `FLOOR()` only deals with integers, you need to scale up the amount by 100, calculate the base amount and scale back down - `FLOOR(100 * Amount / N) / 100`. The residual is then calculated as `Amount - N * BaseAmount`.  From there you just allocated the base amount to all portions adding the residual amount to lust the last allocation.  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sSXVXWBQ). Note that you may need to tweak this if dealing with negative amounts.

Comment: I'm not following your table structure, but I have adapted both of the above approaches to work with tables and apply updates in a single set operation. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JfjikyMl).